# NodeJS mysql app freezing without error - how to diagnose

Tags: mysql, node.js

My Node app is freezing when running a function I've written. The code will stop executing at a specific line on the 11th loop, with no error message. No further requests can be made to the app, and it must be restarted. The data is changing every time it's run, and it is always the 11th iteration.

The function it is calling is relatively complex, so I can't put the code here. My question is how do you approach diagnosing a piece of code when you see no failure notices? I assume the problem is mysql-related, as the last thing logged in the simplified version of the code below is 'Org request start 11' - no error message ever follows. But I don't understand how the code can stop executing here without entering the callback.

Example code is here:

```
async function processDataset(datasets){       
     for (let i = 0; i < datasets.length; i++) {
          const dataset= datasets[i];
          const orgData = await getOrgData(dataset.id);
          const parsedDataset = await processDataset(dataset, orgData);
     }
}



function getOrgData(datasetId) {
   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      console.log("Org request start", datasetId);

      connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
         console.log("got connection");
         if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err);
         }

         connection.query("select * from orgs;", function (error, rows, fields) {
            console.log("query returned");
            connection.release();
            if (error) {
               console.log(error);
               reject(error);
            }  
            resolve(rows);
         });
      });
   });
}
```

Running Node v12 / Express, mysql 5.5

Answer (score 2):

So I found the problem was that elsewhere I had a query running that was missing a line to release the mysql connection in the second function called. Adding this resolved the bug. I don't understand why this doesn't trigger an error, or how I would have gone about diagnosing this with a more systematic approach, so would like to hear any comments.